# NSNotificationCenter selector arguments

Tags: arguments, selector, nsnotifications, nsnotificationcenter

I want to call not just methods from NSNotification but the method's arguments
Something along the lines of

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playerinCombat:YES) name:@"PlayerinCombat" object:nil];
```

and not just

```
@selector(playerinCombat:)
```

just to use with

```
+ (BOOL)playerinCombat:(BOOL)flag {return flag; if (flag){NSLog(@"Player in Combat.");} if (!flag){NSLog(@"Player not in Combat.");}}
```

But it won't work. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass object with NSNotificationCenter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896646/how-to-pass-object-with-nsnotificationcenter)

Comment: In your handler method, you return before running the logging code, which means it will never be called. You should return *after* logging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On second thought userInfo can be used (I think)