# NSNotification: does the object property have to be self?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsnotifications

So far I have been using NSNotificationCenter with the method `postNotification:aString object:anyObjectOfInterestForTheReceiver`. But recently I read in the documentation that the `object` field should only be passed `self`. Is there any terrible side effect I am unaware of that should convince me to only pass `self` in the future, or is it OK to pass any object?
Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass any object as the `object` of a notification, but the convention is that the `object` is the "thing that is doing the notifying" (and you put other relevant state in the `userInfo` dictionary).

The reason why it's mostly `self` is because usually the object doing the notifying usually wants to reference itself. That way, for example, if you had many `Foo` objects, and one of them completed a task and sent a notification, anyone observing the notification could just look at `object` to see which `Foo` was the one in question. The observer can also choose to observe only notifications from a particular `Foo` when you follow this scheme.

It's also reasonable (though less common) to use something besides "self" when posting a notification-- let's say you're sending a notification "on behalf of" another object. For example, you could be a singleton controller object that completes a `Bar` task, and you could send the notification with a reference to the particular `Bar` as the object. That makes more sense than using the singleton as the `object`, since there'd be no interesting variance there.

Again, this is a (useful) convention only. When you make up your own notification, you get to define the "contract" of the notification, which is the name, what kind of object is used as the `object`, and what's in the `userInfo`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a side effect I can think of. Let me explain it.

The method you talk about was actually defined in NSNotification.h as below:

- (void)postNotificationName:(NSString *)notificationName object:(id)notificationSender

The first parameter notificationName stands for the name of the notification.
The second parameter notificationSender stands for the object posting the notification.

Yes, any object can be a notification sender, even nil can be.

In terms of  observering the notification(to became a observer of a specific notification), we got to know another method defined in NSNotification:

- (void)addObserver:(id)notificationObserver selector:(SEL)notificationSelector name:(NSString *)notificationName object:(id)notificationSender

As you can see, the last parameter is notificationSender(the object whose notifications the observer wants to receive).

So right now, the **side effect** is apparently. Let me explain it in detail. There are three controllers A, B, C.for example. The controller A post a notification helloEveryone. The controller B also post a notification helloEveryone.
In C controller, if you place a statement like below:

[[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(helloEveryOne)   name:@"helloEveryone" object:nil]

Then you will receive two helloEveryone from controller A and controller B.
if you place a statement like this:

[[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(helloEveryOne)   name:@"helloEveryone" object:controllerA]

Then you will receive only one helloEveryone from controller A.

The **self** surely is  not a nil notification sender as long as it can post a notification, but use another object as a notification sender, may be it is a nil object. And the observer's behave is different in terms of that whether notification sender is nil or not.

Answer (score 1):

It is crucial if the events really have sender.

When you register an observer, you can specify the sender that you want to observe. If you are letting other people using your message, so it is crucial to pass sender correctly or the observer that bound to specific sender will not get your message.