# NSString IntValue exception when parsing notification userInfo

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsnotificationcenter

I am implementing a login system that uses the `NSNotifications` `userInfo` dictionary to pass login info by notification. The dictionary gets passed ok but when I try to convert one of the `NSStrings` in the dictionary into an int using IntValue I get error. Even when I copy the dictionary object to another string I get the same error, but with a normal string there are no errors. Code:

```
- (void)loginComplete:(NSNotification *) notification {
    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"Login Complete"]) {
        NSDictionary *loginInfo = [notification userInfo];

        loginString = [loginInfo objectForKey:@"login_string"];
        NSLog(@"%@", loginString);
        NSString* expString = [NSString stringWithString:[loginInfo objectForKey:@"expires_in"]];
        // [loginInfo objectForKey:@"expires_in"] == @"604700"
        expiresIn   = [expString intValue];
        NSLog(@"expiresIn: %i", expiresIn);

        NSString * toInt = @"112345";
        int realInt = [toInt intValue];
        NSLog(@"realInt: %i", realInt);
    }
}
```

So the first `NSLog` provides correct info, and the conversion in the end (test) also works, but the expiresIn results in an error:

```
2015-01-13 17:53:06.976 API_test_osx[2867:143430] -[__NSArrayM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000441d40
2015-01-13 17:53:06.976 API_test_osx[2867:143430] *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:didFinishLoadForFrame: delegate: <NSInvalidArgumentException> -[__NSArrayM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000441d40
```

If I try not to convert to int, the value can be logged just fine as a `NSString`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show how you set a userInfo of NSNotification?
Look this question maybe help: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896646/how-to-pass-object-with-nsnotificationcenter
NSArray doens't have objectForKey!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object you think is an `NSString` is in fact an `NSArray` as demonstrated by the error message:

```
-[__NSArrayM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000441d40
```

I cannot provide more information than that, other to say that if you are passing around integers within an Objective-C collection class then use an `NSNumber` object, not an `NSString` object.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. The third party code I used made the values into arrays of 1 length. What kept me from getting it was that I was still able to assign the values into NSString ivars, propably because it called implicitly the NSArrays toString method. I mark your answer as the right one.

Comment: Also prefer using 'NSInteger' rather than 'int' and 'integerValue' rather than 'intValue'

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your accessing an array of objects under the key you specify. You will also need to access the objects index value. Ie objectAtIndex. Hope this helps

Comment: Yeah, doing that now. Thanks.