# How to access data passed in iOS notification (simple)?

Tags: ios, cocoa, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotification

Trying to get one ViewController to communicate with another through standard Cocoa Notifications.

Wrote a simple test case. In my initial VC I add the following to viewDidLoad:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
 selector: @selector(mesageReceived:)
 name:@"test.channel.pw" object:nil];
```

I add the following method:

```
- (void)mesageReceived:(NSNotification *)notif
{
    NSString *text = (NSString *)notif;    
}
```

I then segue to a VC which has the following added to its viewDidLoad:

```
  NSString *test = @"someText";
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     postNotificationName:@"test.channel.pw" object:test];
```

When I run it, the notification works - the messageReceived method is called - but the value of text is "test.channel.pw", not "someText" as I expected.

What is going on here, and what is the correct syntax for passing a reference to a class instance using notifications?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass object with NSNotificationCenter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896646/how-to-pass-object-with-nsnotificationcenter)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your data using [userInfo](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotificationCenter/postNotificationName:object:userInfo:) dictionary.

Change the notification passing code like:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"test.channel.pw" object:nil userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"someText" forKey:@"dataKey"]];
```

And change the receiver method like:

```
- (void)mesageReceived:(NSNotification *)notif
{
    NSString *text = [[notif userInfo] objectForKey:@"dataKey"];    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `NSString *text = (NSString *)[notif object];`.

Answer (score 0):

By this

```
-(void)someMethod{
  NSDictionary *postDict = @{@"Key":[NSNumber numberWithFloat:17.0]};
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"myNotification" object:postDict];
}
```

Some other class

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"myNotification" object:nil userInfo:postDict];
}
-(void)valueForNotification:(NSNotification *)notification{
NSDictionary *dict = [notification userInfo];
NSLog(@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"Key"]); //prints out 17.0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass only NSDictionary object in NSnotificationCenter. Through NSDictionary you can pass any data and then you need to parse once received.