# How to bring value from a UIviewController using delegate without instantiating object

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, delegates, uistoryboard

I have 3 UIViewControllers say:
v1ViewController
v2ViewController
v3ViewController.

I have pushed controllers as v2 on v1 and v3 on v2.
Now I want to bring some value back to v1ViewController from v3ViewController using delegates.
On v3Viewcontroller I wrote it:

```
for vc in self.navigationController!.viewControllers{
            if vc is v1ViewController{
                delegate?.returnFilteredImage(imageView.image!)
                self.navigationController?.popToViewController(vc, animated: true)
            }

        }
```

How can I use delegates because in v1ViewController I haven't create object of v3Viewcontroller; consequently I cannot connect delegate to self.

So how can i do that.

Comment: You can use key value observing: http://nshipster.com/key-value-observing/

Comment: Have you tried with NSNotificationCenter observer. If it's only related to passing a value maybe this can be useful

Comment: @AnkitaShah Notification is the easy way here but i want to try it through delegation

Answer (score 0):

**1.** **Using delgates**

create a protocol and implement in your firstviewcontroller

```
 protocol My {
 func returnFilteredImage(image: UIImage)
} 

 class FirstViewController: UIViewcontroller, My {

  ...
  func returnFilteredImage(image: UIImage) {
 }

}
```

and in your thirdViewController create a property and assign FirstViewController delegate to this.

```
class ThirdViewController: UIViewController {
  var delegate: My?
  ...

 override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

 for vc in self.navigationController!.viewControllers{
        if vc is FirstViewController {

        let vc1 = vc as! FirstViewController
        self.delegate = vc1

            self.delegate?.returnFilteredImage(imageView.image!)
            self.navigationController?.popToViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }

    }
}

}
```

**2.** **Using local notifications**
[check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36910965/how-can-i-pass-received-data-through-nsnotificationcenter-in-my-swift-ios-app/36911168#36911168)

You can do this using local notifications

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //add observer
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.didgetImage(_:)), name: "receiveImageNotification", object: nil)

 } 

func didgetImage(notification: NSNotification) {

if let image = notification.userInfo?["image"] as? UIImage {
  // do something with your image
 }
}

}
```

and from third view controller, first notification

```
let imageDataDict:[String: UIImage] = ["image": image]


NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("receiveImageNotification", object: self, userInfo: imageDataDict)
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: it will throw error ` self.delegate = vc` as we cannot assign delegate to view controller

Comment: but how can we set delegate to that class

Comment: already update answer. please check
 let vc1 = vc as! FirstViewController
  self.delegate = vc1