# Force refresh on another ViewController component with swift

Tags: swift, nsviewcontroller

I'm trying to pass a trigger between 2 view controller but i can't find something that works ...

I have the main controller with a NSTableView, source linked, View Base.

main Controller class :

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
```

I have an array defined in Global variables.
on the viewDidLoad i add 2 elements in my array, then i use setDelegate and setDataSource.
It works fine.

```
myLib.myCoins =  fillCoinsTable()
print ("My lib has \(myLib.myCoins.count) objects ")
mainCoinTable.setDelegate(self)
mainCoinTable.setDataSource(self)
```

I have a segue from the WINDOWS CONTROLLER to my second view Controller.
(It's a ToolBar button). The segue is "Sheet" kind.

This second controller allows me to add an element in my global variable arrays, with a button "Save" .

Code on the second controller

```
@IBAction func addCoinButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        //We add the coin
        let newCoin:coin = coin(n: textName.stringValue)
        newCoin.Year =  Int.init(textYear.stringValue)

        myLib.myCoins.append(newCoin)

        self.dismissController(self)

    }
```

If i add a button on the main controller, to reloadData on the TableView, it works fine. The third element is added.

but i would like that to be automatic ....

I tried segue, but mine is not between view controller but with the windows controller.

Can you please help ?

Thanks,
Nicolas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, you want to add data from oneViewController and without pressing button, you want after navigation or pressing back button, you want to reload automatically tableview to show updated results, right.

If I'm not wrong then, this solution will work for you.

Follow this below steps:

Step 1 :

Add this code in your view controller, from which you want to add data in array or in database, instead of button click.

```
 override func viewDidLoad()
        {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            let backItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "goBack")
            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backItem
     }

     func goBack()
        {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("load", object: nil)
                 self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
        }
```

Step 2:

Now its final step. 
Now add this below code, to your result view controller, where you want to automatically update the result.

```
 func loadList(notification: NSNotification){
        self.TableView.reloadData()
    }

 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
       NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "loadList:",name:"load", object: nil)

    }
```

Now implement this code-stuff in your coding. Hope it works for you.

Comment: Welcome mate :) Happy Coding :)

Comment: And if you need to pass data, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36911168/529663

Answer (score 0):

If you want the table to reload automatically when the View appears add this to `viewWillAppear`

```
self.tableView.performSelectorOnMainThread(#selector(UITableView.reloadData), withObject: nil, waitUntilDone: true)
```

Comment: This is the code in my main ViewController : self.mainCoinTable.performSelectorOnMainThread(#selector(NSTableView.reloadData), withObject: nil, waitUntilDone: true) in the override override func viewWillAppear(). But this function is not called when on my second controller i use self.dismiss.