# Objective-C observer - how to use in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift3

I'm adding new features with Swift to Objective-C app.

I have this observer in Objective-C (registration.m):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:NOTIFICATION_SERVER_SENT_CONFIRMATION_SMS object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(confirmSms) name:NOTIFICATION_SERVER_SENT_CONFIRMATION_SMS object:nil];
```

and in confirm.m:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIFICATION_SERVER_SENT_CONFIRMATION_SMS object:nil];
```

How to observe this in Swift? I've tried

```
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self,
                                                  name: NOTIFICATION_SERVER_SENT_CONFIRMATION_SMS,
                                                  object:nil);

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                              selector:#selector(self.confirmationSmsSent),
                                              name: NOTIFICATION_SERVER_SENT_CONFIRMATION_SMS,
                                              object: nil);
```

And I'm getting

> Use of unresolved identifier
>   'NOTIFICATION_SERVER_SENT_CONFIRMATION_SMS'

Thanks

**// EDIT:**

I have declared in Obj-C:

```
NSString *const NOTIFICATION_SERVER_SENT_CONFIRMATION_SMS = @"confirmationSMSSent";
```

Will this still work with this?

```
let name: NSNotification.Name = NSNotification.Name("Your_Notification_Name_Key_String") //NOTIFICATION_SERVER_SENT_CONFIRMATION_SMS
```

And when I use

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(self.confirmationSmsSent(_:)), name: name, object: nil)

func confirmationSmsSent(notification: NSNotification) {

}
```

I got error

> Value of type 'MyController' has no member 'confirmationSmsSent'

on

> NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(self.confirmationSmsSent(_:)), name: name, object: nil)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36910965/how-to-pass-data-using-notificationcentre-in-swift-3-0-and-nsnotificationcenter/36911168#36911168

Comment: in witch file you've declared NOTIFICATION_SERVER_SENT_CONFIRMATION_SMS variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Swift 3, the syntax is changed. You have to define the variable of `NSNotification.Name`

```
let name: NSNotification.Name = NSNotification.Name("Your_Notification_Name_Key_String") //NOTIFICATION_SERVER_SENT_CONFIRMATION_SMS

//Add Notification
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(self.yourSelector(_:)), name: name, object: nil)

//Remove Notification Observer
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: name, object: nil)

//Your Selector
func yourSelector(_ notification: Notification) {
//Code
}
```

Comment: and self.yourSelector(_:) shoud be defined as func yourSelector()? What should be in () as param? On func confirmationSmsSent(notification: NSNotification) {} I'm getting on the selector error **Value of type 'MyController' has no member 'confirmationSmsSent'**

Comment: @sohil-r-memon Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is because you not yet declared NOTIFICATION_SERVER_SENT_CONFIRMATION_SMS.

Normally notification name is just a string, btw you must cast it to nested NSNotification.Name type.

```
let NOTIFICATION_SERVER_SENT_CONFIRMATION_SMS = NSNotification.Name("<some string>")
```

Answer (score 1):

The most useful swift - lije code is extension

```
extension Notification.Name {
static let someNewName = "ThatsItImAwsome" 
}
```

Usage inside post :

`.someNewKey`

this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(self.yourSelector(_:)), name: .someNewKey, object: nil)
```