# show viewController from collectionView without storyboards

Tags: swift, delegates, uicollectionview, segue, uicollectionviewcell

I am having some trouble showing a viewController programmatically (without storyboards) from a collectionView. I would think this is pretty easy but I am having some difficulty figuring this out as I am somewhat new to swift. I believe collectionViewCells are not delegates by default, so I have tried implementing the didSelectItemAt in the collectionView class but still no luck. On tap of the cell I am receiving a print statement, just not having any show segue. See collectionViewCell code below, and thanks in advance!

```
// collectionViewCell class
class PlanningCell: BaseCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.dataSource = self
        cv.delegate = self
        return cv
    }()

    //collectionViewCell variables
    var plannedPlaces = [CurrentPlanner]()   
    let cellId = "cellId"

    var basePlanningCell: BasePlanningCell!

    override func setupViews() {
        super.setupViews()
        addSubview(collectionView)

        collectionView.register(BasePlanningCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return plannedPlaces.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! BasePlanningCell
        cell.currentPlanner = plannedPlaces[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("did tap")
        let plannersDetailVC = PlanningPlaceDetailsVC()
        plannersDetailVC.navigationTitle = plannedPlaces[(indexPath.row)].planningPlace
        // below I am receiving the use of unresolved identifier "show" error
        show(plannersDetailVC, sender: self)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, when you want to present another view controoler, you need to call this function

```
self.present(yourViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

However, you cannot do that in the place you do the print because the function `present` is only available in view controllers. So now the problem becomes, how to direct your cell click to the parent view controller and pass a string. You have two options, you can either create a delegate like [this](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/quick-guide-to-swift-delegates/), or do a [NSNotificationCenter post call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36911168/5838902), the second one being easier.

When you pass the cell click event to your parent view controller, you can start calling that method mention above to navigate to another view controoler

Comment: thanks, but its now giving me the error message "Value of type 'PlanningCell' has no member 'present' "

Comment: @user3708224 Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VCIdentifier") as! PlanningPlaceDetailsVC
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Don't forget to set the PlanningPlaceDetailsVC **Identifier**

Updated for a VC setted by code:

```
let vc : UIViewController = PlanningPlaceDetailsVC()
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I am not using storyboards at all.