# Referencing another UIViewController Causes a nil pointer and creates a new object

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am creating a calculator app in which I need to set a variable in a separate view controller from a settings page. When attempting this feat some weird things happen. First, it somehow the variable returns nil. Then, it initialized a new view controller. Yet, all the non-static variables are the same when I reopen an instance of the old view controller.

There might be an error in my code:

```
func updateTag(title: String){
    switch(title){
    case "displayWithPrecisionSwitch":
        let mainViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "timerViewController") as! ViewController
        mainViewController.updatePercision()
        mainViewController.correctTallyDisplay?.refresh(totalTime: mainViewController.counter.getIntegerTime(), goal: mainViewController.counter.getGoal())
        mainViewController.incorrectTallyDisplay?.refresh(totalTime: mainViewController.counter.getIntegerTime(), goal: mainViewController.counter.getGoal())
        print(mainViewController.correctTallyDisplay?.percision ?? "Warning Nil")
    default:
        print("break")
        break;
    }
}
```

Or in the UI: enter image description here
[image]
I just need to find a way to call functions from "timerViewController".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are initializing a new view controller when you call`storyboard?.instantiateViewController` and you should not be doing that. To simply call a method in another view controller, you can use `NSNotificationCenter` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36911168/5838902), or create a [delegate](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/quick-guide-to-swift-delegates/) to achieve the same result. The first one is easier to implement.

Here is an example if you just need to call a method from another view controller. Lets say your caller view controller is trying to call a method in your callee controller.

So in your callee controller, you need to resister to receive this type of call in your `viewDidLoad` method. So put this code there to do the registration

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(methodOfReceivedNotification(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("NotificationIdentifier"), object: nil)
```

Then you need the method that this notification is calling

```
func methodOfReceivedNotification(notification: Notification){
    //either replace the function name to your function or call your function here
}
```

Then in your caller view controller which is setting view controller or any other view controller, when you want to call this registered method, simply do

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("NotificationIdentifier"), object: nil)
```

Comment: @macrocypher Edited my answer with simple set ups