# How to tell when AVPlayer has been played for three seconds Swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, avplayer

I have an application that contains videos that play automatically in an `UIImageView` in a `UITableView` when the cell is visible, and all I am trying to do is allow the application to know when the video has been played for three seconds. I wrote this code.

```
    class PostCell: UITableViewCell {

    var player: AVPlayer?
    var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer?

    var post: Post? {
    didSet {
        updateView()
    }
}

    func updateView() {

    self.viewcount()

    if let videoUrlString = post?.videoUrl, let videoUrl = URL(string: videoUrlString) {
        player = AVPlayer(url: videoUrl)
        playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        playerLayer?.frame = postImageView.frame
        playerLayer?.frame.size.width = postImageView.frame.size.width
        playerLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        self.contentView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer!)

        player?.play()
    }
      func viewcount() {
    if let currentitem = player?.currentItem {
        if currentitem.currentTime() == CMTimeMake(3, 1) {
            print ("VIDEO PLAYED FOR THREE SECONDS")
        }
      }
   }
}
```

but it is not printing out my message once the video starts playing. I have searched the web for help but couldn't find anything on this subject. So could anyone please help with my issue and tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer#dash_1385829

Comment: Specifically: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1388027-addboundarytimeobserver

Comment: Try calling self.viewcount() after player.Play() as in self.viewcount() you are checking player current time and its not playing anything at that time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are searching for observer of player here is how you can check and track the current position of AVPlayer

Here is function that is adding observer to cell

```
private func addObserversForVideoPlayer(cell:CustomCell) {

   let observer =  cell.player?.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTime.init(seconds: 1, preferredTimescale: 1), queue: .main, using: {[weak self,weak cell] (time) in
        guard let cell = cell else {return}

        if cell.player?.currentItem?.status == .readyToPlay {
            // print("Inside Will DISPLAY\(cell.video.currentTime)")

            let timeDuration : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds((cell.player?.currentItem?.asset.duration)!)
            cell.lblDuration.text = self?.getDurationFromTime(time: timeDuration)

            let currentTime : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds((cell.player?.currentTime())!)
            cell.lblStart.text = self?.getDurationFromTime(time: currentTime)
            cell.slider.maximumValue = Float(timeDuration.rounded())
            cell.slider.value = Float(currentTime.rounded())

        }
    })
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: cell.player?.currentItem, queue: .main, using: {[weak cell,weak self]  (notification) in

        if cell?.player != nil {
            cell?.player?.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
            cell?.player?.play()
        }
    })
}
```

so that    `addPeriodicTimeObserver` will notify you when the player start playing.

And `NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime` will notify you when your AVPlayer stops.

Note1: If your `cell.player?.currentItem` is nil while you are adding `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime` it will be cause bug see this [One AVPlayer's AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime action executed for all Currently playing videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49403336/one-avplayers-avplayeritemdidplaytoendtime-action-executed-for-all-currently-pl) , If . you don't need it don't add it :)

Note2: You should keep `observer` so after time you can remove it so that can not take extra load on memory

Hope it is helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the view count after player had started playing

```
func updateView() {

    /// Not here Because at this time player current item is not initiated yet
    /// if you use Breakpoints in viewCount code you will see it won't enter
    /// in if condition created
    self.viewcount() /// Comment this line
    if let videoUrlString = post?.videoUrl, let videoUrl = URL(string: videoUrlString) {
        player = AVPlayer(url: videoUrl)
        playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        playerLayer?.frame = postImageView.frame
        playerLayer?.frame.size.width = postImageView.frame.size.width
        playerLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        self.contentView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer!)
        /// Player is initiated with a item to play
        player?.play()
        /// Call current time here
        /// Now it will Enter in if Condition 
        /// Also try using else statement so you know Do control enter in if or in Else
        self.viewcount()
    }


func viewcount()
    {
        if let currentitem = player?.currentItem
        {
            ///Yes Player have a item whose time can be Detected
            if currentitem.currentTime() == CMTimeMake(3, 1)
            {
                print ("VIDEO PLAYED FOR THREE SECONDS")
            }
        }
        else
        {
            /// Check do Control reach here in case 1 When you are calling before player.play()
        }
    }
```