# How to update informations of UITableViewController when IBAction of a cell is triggered?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a `UITableViewController` with custom `UITableViewCell`, and every cell has an `UISwitch` inside.

Need to update an information on my table (a string in the header), when any of these switches turn on/off (need to display the number of switches on in the section header).

I'm not confident with iOS and UIKit, but I've already found 2 possibile solutions:

1. implement a delegate pattern between cell and table controller
2. write update logic inside the function `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

In the first solution my `TableViewController` conforms to

```swift
protocol TableViewDelegate {
  func reloadTable()
}
```

that update its inner counter of switches on - and update the header section in function `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?` - calling

```swift
DispatchQueue.main.async{
  self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Obviously my custom `UITableViewCell` has the reference to the delegate `TableViewController` and call its `reloadTable()`.

The second solution instead is about the possibility to get the information of every cell in the method `cellForRowAt indexPath`. I've found that this function in not only called when the table has to be drawn, but also when I interact with a component into a cell.

So I need to implement a counting in the function `cellForRowAt indexPath`? Or the first solution with delegate pattern is a good one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use a delegate in your cell.. can go like this

```
protocol CellDelegate: class {
   func actionDidPressed()
}
```

then in your cell should use it

```
class cell: UITableViewCell {
    weak var delegate: CellDelegate?

    @IBAction func buttonPressed() {
       delegate?.actionDidPressed()
    }

 }
```

then lastly in your controller you can conform to it

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

     // in your cellAtIndexPath method after creating cell you can 

     cell.delegate = self 

}
```

I prefer to make an extension to the View Controller to conform to delegates

```
extension ViewController: CellDelegate {
  func actionDidPressed() {
      // add the action you need here 
   }
}
```

Comment: Ok, this is exactly my first solution (my favorite). And it works. I was looking for a confirm, or an alternative good way. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Like @Shunzhe said.. NSNotification is also a way.. but i would not use it in such situation cause you'll have to make sure you removed the observer from each cell after end using it.. it's a big tricky and can be a pitfall.. plus the code will be smelly after a while

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSNotification to pass data between different views. You'll need to register the recipient controller by using the `addObserver` method and use post to send a message. You can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36910965/how-to-pass-data-using-notificationcenter-in-swift-3-0-and-nsnotificationcenter)