# Swift passing parameters in #selector calls

Tags: swift, onclick, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

to sum up my problem: I have a bigger table with lots of posts from different people. And I am going through my list of tablecells with the datasource of the tableview like in the following example. And I want to give each textlabel of the cell a click listener. So I came up with this here in my cellForRowAt at my tables datasource:

```
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(clickedOnLabel(sender:, content: local[indexPath.row][2],rank: rank)))
    cell.textLabel?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    cell.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

So I wanna add this click funktion right here, which needs the arguments content and rank with it:

```
@objc func clickedOnLabel(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer, content: String, rank: Int){

    //Do some stuff here

}
```

But I am not allowed to pass content and rank with the selector, when I put content and rank out, everything works fine... So is it just syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example of how you can achieve this by using closures.

```
cell.updateParent = { [weak self] score, rank in
    // Do magic here
}
```

And in your cell class you should add something like

```
var updateParent: ((Double, Int) -> Void)?

@IBAction func doMagicInParent(_ sender: Any) {
    updateParent?(score, rank)
}
```

This can be achieved by using delegates as well. Or you can also pass the data through the notification center.

[Notification center example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36910965/how-to-pass-data-using-notificationcenter-in-swift-3-0-and-nsnotificationcenter)

[Delegate example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099230/delegates-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using delegate:

### In your custom cell

```
protocol MyCustomCellDelegate{
    func didTapOnLabel(content: String, rank: Int)
}

var delegate: MyCustomCellDelegate?
```

When tap happens, call

```
self.delegate?.didTapOnLabel(content: "my content", rank: 100)
```

### In your CellForRowAt Function

```
cell.delegate = self
```

and conform the delegate:

```
extension YouViewController: MyCustomCellDelegate{
    func didTapOnLabel(content: String, rank: Int){
        // do your stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: But how am I supposed to know what to fill in my content and rank at your "When tap happens, call" because I cant pass my the objectivec function? And also I cant give my cell a delegate...

Comment: Here is one more question, how are we supposed to know that you can't pass your objective-c function when you did not even mention this in the original question?

Comment: @CaipiDE you need to trigger the delegate function in the objective c function implementation. Also I showed how to make delegation for your cell. Please read the instructions well.