# swift - How to make Add to Favorites with NSURL array

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to build an app stores specific sounds which user can play. I assure you I've searched for 2 days but I couldn't what I look for. (Or I couldn't successful with those tuts idk)

The app stores sounds like this:

```
var sound1 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Adios Amigos", ofType: "mp3")!)
var sound2 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ses2", ofType: "mp3")!)
var sound3 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ses3", ofType: "mp3")!)
var sound4 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ses4", ofType: "mp3")!)



    var soundArray: [NSURL] = [sound1, sound2, sound3, sound4]
```

here is my button that play sounds as random:

```
    @IBAction func Rastgele(sender: Any) {

            let randNo = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(soundArray.count))) // 0...ArrayCount

            do {
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
                try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: (soundArray[randNo] as NSURL) as URL)
                audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
                audioPlayer.play()

                self.sesLabel.text = soundArray[randNo].deletingPathExtension?.lastPathComponent
                soundIndex = randNo} catch {
                print(error)
            }

}
```

and here is my IBAction button that I couldn't fill inside with code.

```
       @IBAction func Favori(_ sender: Any) {
// empty    
        }
```

I tried to use NSUserdefaults but I couldn't achieve what I want. 
I also tried to pull the array item from my array to insert another array but I faced many problems with because of type of array(NSURL)

So, 'Favori' button should store as Favorites then I can show favorited sounds in other table view.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I found a solution using Core Data and converting NSURLs to URL. Thanks to the @rmaddy for helpful comment. The working code is down below;

```
@IBAction func Favori(_ sender: Any) {



        // save core data
        let app = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = app.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let newSound = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Sounds", in: context)
        let sound = NSManagedObject(entity: newSound!, insertInto: context)



        sound.setValue(soundArray[soundIndex].deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent, forKey: "soundName")


        do {  try context.save()

            soundItems.append(sound)

            print(sound)
        }
        catch
        {
            print("error")
        }

    }
```

Comment: If anything wrong with my question just let me know so I can fix it.

Comment: Why are you using `NSURL` and not `URL`?

Comment: Ooops. I tried to use URL once and I got an error but I tried it again after you commented. It won't give me an error. I'm gonna be cancer -_-' 

what is the different between url and nsurl ?

Comment: `URL` is the proper Swift API. `NSURL` is the old Objective-C class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on the button, save the URL into [core data](https://www.raywenderlich.com/145809/getting-started-core-data-tutorial) or a [local data base](https://www.raywenderlich.com/123579/sqlite-tutorial-swift) using sqlite or a server.
If you just want to pass it to another tableview without saving it (data will lost when you kill the app), you can pass that around using a [delegate](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/quick-guide-to-swift-delegates/) or [notification center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896646/how-to-pass-object-with-nsnotificationcenter).

Comment: How can I do that ? There is a tutorial about core data but they're all about string type values. My problem starts with NSURL.

Comment: You can store the mp3 file name